# Тип придаточного и знак препинания в таких случаях

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, сложное-предложение, тип-придаточных

*С кем ни общаешься (, / —) все хотят свой бизнес.*

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это придаточное **уступительное.** Основным вариантом является запятая, тире ставится при наличии авторской паузы:

(1) С кем ни общаешься, все хотят свой бизнес. (2) С кем ни общаешься — все хотят свой бизнес.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=142#pp142

Тире ставится для интонационного отделения главной части сложноподчиненного предложения от придаточной. Чаще всего тире употребляется в тех случаях, когда главной части предшествует:

3) придаточная **уступительная**: Пускай, как хотят, тиранят, пускай хоть кожу с живой снимут — я воли своей не отдам (С.‑Щ.); **Сколько бы ни смотреть на море — оно никогда не надоест** (Кат.).

**О предложении**

Это относительный подтип придаточного предложения с обобщенно-уступительным значением, в этом случае описываются обобщенные или повторяющиеся ситуации.

Answer (score 1):

В приведенном предложении придаточное определяет, кто такие *все*, следовательно, его тип — определительное.

Можно поставить и тире (т. к. придаточное имеет уточняющий характер), и запятую.

Так, корректно:

> С кем ни общаешься — все хотят свой бизнес.

и

> С кем ни общаешься, все хотят свой бизнес.